# Undefined value using redux

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I'll post the code and make the question at the end.

**SignUpScreen.js**

```
export default class SignUpScreen extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
}

validateConfirmationPassword() {
  const { username } = this.props;

  console.log("TEST >> " + username);
}

render() {
  const { username, password, email, confirmPassword } = this.props;

  <Input
    placeholder="Username"
    value={username}
    onChangeText= {(value) => this.props.onChangeText('username', value)}
  />

  <Button
    onPress={() => this.validateConfirmationPassword()}
  />
}
```

**SignUpScreen_reducer.js**

```
export default function reducer(state={
  username: '',
  email: '',
  password: '',
  confirmPassword: '',

  usernameError: false,
  emailError: false,
  passwordError: false,
}, action) {

const { type, payload } = action

switch(type) {

    case 'ON_CHANGE_UI_FIELD' : {
        return {...state, [payload.key]: payload.value}
    }
    default: {
        return state
    }
}
```

**SignUpScreenContainer.js**

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    ...state,
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onChangeText: (key, value) => {
      dispatch(onChangeField(key, value))
    },
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SignUpScreen);
```

**SignUpScreen_actions.js**

```
export function onChangeField(key, value) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: 'ON_CHANGE_UI_FIELD', payload: {key, value}})
  }
}
```

**PS: I removed part of the code that was unecessary (like buttons and input texts). If more code is needed, please let me know.**

My question is: What am I doing wrong? I keep getting 'undefined' on my console.log("TEST") for username, password, email and everything else. I have my store set up correctly. Also I can see the values being received on the actions and on the reducer, with the correct 'key' and 'value'.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why aren't SignUpScreenContainer.js and SignUpScreen.js in the same file?

Comment: inside of `mapStateToProps()` can you please do `console.log(state)` and share the structure of the result?

Comment: i think the problem is with 'this', as it is losing scope inside function "validateConfirmationPassword", can you console log this.props ?

Comment: Your `validateConfirmationPassword` is unbound; either `bind` in the ctor or use an arrow function.

Comment: @DaveNewton did that, still the same error

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky hi, i got this:

Object { "signUpScreenReducer": Object { "email": "", "emailError": false, "password": "", "passwordError": false, "username": "", "usernameError": false, }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to do two things to resolve this issue. First as other have mentioned you need to bind `validateConfirmationPassword()` in the constructor to ensure the function has the proper context when being called by `onPress`:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.validateConfirmationPassword = this.validateConfirmationPassword.bind(this);
}
```

Second you would need to adjust how you area attempting to access `username`. You indicated that when you are logging `state` inside `mapStateToProps()`, you are seeing an object such as `{ "signUpScreenReducer": { "email": "", "emailError": false, "password": "", "passwordError": false, "username": "", "usernameError": false, }`. You are trying to access `username` it as `const { username } = this.props;`, but everything is nested within property `signUpScreenReducer`. You would need to access it like:

```
const { username } = this.props.signUpScreenReducer;
```

Or you could change your `mapStateToProps()` to Object spread the actual properties of the `signUpScreenReducer` (state.signUpScreenReducer) object:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ signUpScreenReducer }) => {
  return {
    ...signUpScreenReducer,
  }
}
```

You don't even need spread, you could just also:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ signUpScreenReducer }) => signUpScreenReducer;
```

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

-Just Replace your validateConfirmationPassword function with below version.

```
validateConfirmationPassword = () => {
  const { username } = this.props;

  console.log("TEST >> " + username);
}
```

OR do binding for that function in constructor as below

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.validateConfirmationPassword = this.validateConfirmationPassword.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: @MuhammadSadiq did both of them and neither worked. I added the log on the mapStateToProps like you asked and got this:
Object {
  "signUpScreenReducer": Object {
  "email": "",
  "emailError": false,
  "password": "",
  "passwordError": false,
  "username": "",
  "usernameError": false,
},